# PHP equivalent of VB IIf to ignore blank lines

Tags: php, magento2

I am new to PHP and I am trying to show an address and ignore blank lines, in VB i would use

```
IIf(IsDBNull(bs.Item(0).Row("column"))
```

I cant figure out the PHP equivalent for

```
$Street_lines  = $shipping_Street[0] . "<br/>" . $shipping_Street[1] . "<br/>" . $shipping_Street[2];
```

If I try using

```
if (empty($shipping_Street[0]))
```

I get an unexpected if error

The result I am looking for is for example, if `$shipping_Street[0]` is blank it would set

```
$Street_lines  = $shipping_Street[1] . "<br/>" . $shipping_Street[2]
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: `$Street_lines = (empty($shipping_Street[0]) ? "" : $shipping_Street[0]) . ...`

Comment: Thats perfect Barmar, thanks for your help